# Restore amplify backend environment

Tags: backup, aws-amplify, restore

I've gotten an Amplify project dropped in my lap where the backend environment is deleted (or lost when the project were moved to another account).

I haven't worked with Amplify before, so I'm not sure how "automatic" everything is.

I noticed that the project has a folder called 'amplify-backup' which contain a bunch of json and graphql config files, so I assumed that I could use those somehow to restore the backend environment in AWS, but I can't seem to find any information on how to do so.

There's currently no backend environment in the AWS console and I don't really know which services the backend environment should contain.
Is it possible to restore the backend environment and all the services that the application need or do I need to figure out which services are needed?
If so, any pointers on how to find which services that are used?

Answer (score 0):

If the project files still exist (amplify directory), you may be able to re-create the project with the existing resources.

One idea could be to clone the git repository from when the amplify project files were intact and run `amplify init`

OR

`amplify-backup` is generally generated automatically when doing commands with amplify. You could try rename to `amplify` and run `amplify init`.

See more here for re-creating an amplify project on another account: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/cli-migrate-aws-account/